# How to find the CMD command of a docker image?

Tags: docker

I have a docker image installed and I'd like to check what is its CMD command. Is there any cli command to do so?
for example, I'd like it to tell me that this docker image CMD is ["rails","server"]

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You can use the [`docker inspect`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect) command:

```bash
docker inspect --format='{{.Config.Cmd}}' <image:tag>
docker inspect -f '{{.Config.Cmd}}' <image:tag>
```

That is used, for instance, to "[list full command of running/stopped container in Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27380853/6309)".

> The `inspect` method is not correct because it distorts the actual command.
> Let's say the `CMD` is `["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]`.
> The `inspect` method will return a single string `nginx -g daemon off;` which not equivalent, and is actually incorrect (`daemon off;` should be a single argument)!

From [Łukasz Zaroda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1326863/%c5%81ukasz-zaroda)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77163178/6309):

```bash
docker history --no-trunc nginx:1.25.1-alpine | grep -m 1 -Po "(?<=CMD \[).+(?=\])" "nginx" "-g" "daemon off;"
```

Łukasz has a valid point about the loss of information concerning how individual elements in the `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` instruction are quoted or escaped. That could be significant when reconstructing or understanding the command, as certain elements could be intended to be passed as single arguments to the entry point script or executable.

The `docker history --no-trunc` method coupled with `grep` and regular expression matching is a more robust solution in this regard. That method preserves the original argument boundaries, allowing for a more accurate representation of the command as specified in the image.

---

As noted in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30441035/how-to-find-the-cmd-command-of-a-docker-image/30441184?noredirect=1#comment48981876_30441184) by [user2915097](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2915097/user2915097) and [Lenormju](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11384184/lenormju), an alternative would be, using [`docker history --no-trunc`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/history/):

```bash
docker history --no-trunc zenithar/nano-nginx | awk ' NR==2 {print}'
```

Comment: while docker inspect is THE way to go, as a docker image has this command in his last layer, a trick could be to use something like  `docker history zenithar/nano-nginx | awk ' NR==2 {print}'`  but the drawback is that the command is truncated.

Comment: @user2915097 does a dockerfile has to terminate with CMD though?

Comment: no, it may be a CMD, ENTRYPOINT, or nothing. We are back at docker inspect so :-)

Comment: @user2915097 now there is a `--no-trunc` option for the [`docker history` command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/history/)

Comment: @Lenormju Thank you for this feedback. I have included this alternative (amended with `--no-trunc` in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: The inspect method is not correct because it distorts the actual command. Let's say the CMD is `["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]` . The inspect method will return a single string `nginx -g daemon off;` which not equivalent, and is actually incorrect (`daemon off;` should be a single argument)!

Comment: @ŁukaszZaroda Very good point. I have upvoted your answer and included your command (and a link to your answer) in mine.

Answer (score 4):

If it's running, you can use

`docker inspect -f "{{.Path}} {{.Args}} ({{.Id}})" $(docker ps -a -q)`

Shamlessley pulled from [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39479708/514402)

Answer (score 3):

I believe the `docker inspect -f '{{.Config.Cmd}}' <image:tag>` method is not correct because the value returned by this command may be wrong. Example:

```
$ docker inspect -f '{{.Config.Cmd}}' nginx:1.25.1-alpine
[nginx -g daemon off;]
```

What is messed up here is that in the actual entrypoint the `daemon off;` is a **single argument**. This information is lost in the output of the `docker inspect` command.

The better command would be:

```
$ docker history --no-trunc nginx:1.25.1-alpine | grep -m 1 -Po "(?<=CMD \[).+(?=\])"
"nginx" "-g" "daemon off;"
```

This allows us to correctly reconstruct the used command. The same applies to the entrypoint.

So, I believe that the better/reliable way of extracting CMD/ENTRYPOINT information is:

```
docker history --no-trunc <image:tag> | grep -m 1 -Po "(?<=CMD \[).+(?=\])"
docker history --no-trunc <image:tag> | grep -m 1 -Po "(?<=ENTRYPOINT \[).+(?=\])"
```