# Run shell script on docker from shared volume

Tags: docker, sh

I have a docker container that has a shared volume with the host.  The volume mounts in the root home folder.  In that folder, I have a shell script I want to run once the container is up and running.

I was using this command:

```
docker exec -i localserver_web_1 sh /root/scripts/define_applications.sh
```

but I'm getting this response:

```
sh: 0: Can't open /root/scripts/define_applications.sh
```

The script is working fine when I run it from inside the container.  It says it's in /root/scripts/.  I have permissions set at 777.  What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: this turned out to be a pebkac error, but @VonC 's answer helped me diagnose the problem and may be helpful to others.

Answer (score 2):

Just to be sure, try and exec as root, with a tty, in a command shell:

```
docker exec -it -u root localserver_web_1 sh -c '/root/scripts/define_applications.sh'
```

If it does not work, check at least its presence and content through [`docker exec`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/):

```
docker exec -it -u root localserver_web_1 sh -c 'ls -alrt /root/scripts'
docker exec -it -u root localserver_web_1 sh -c 'cat /root/scripts/define_applications.sh'
```

Also inspect the image to check its `ENTRYPOINT` (similar [to the check for its `CMD`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30441184/6309)):

```
docker inspect --format='{{.Config.Entrypoint}}' <image:tag>
```

The [OP Jon Schwartz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/513592/jon-schwartz) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34188041/run-shell-script-on-docker-from-shared-volume/34189385#comment56153260_34189385):

> this was a pebkac error.
>   The script is actually called `define-applications.sh`, not `define_applications.sh`.
>   The `cat` line showed me my issue. When it could see the script through ls, I knew it should be able to get to it. When it couldn't `cat` out, I realized what happened.

Comment: thanks so much you helped me solve my issue... unfortunately, this was a pebkac error.  The script is actually called define-applications.sh  not define_applications.sh  The cat line showed me my issue.  When it could see the script through ls, I knew it should be able to get to it.  When it couldn't cat out, I realized what happened.  oops.  thanks!

Comment: @JonSchwartz Great! I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility.