# Docker: Unable to run shell script stored in a mounted volume

Tags: linux, windows, shell, docker

I am running Docker (1.10.2) on **Windows**. I created a script to echo 'Hello World' on my machine and stored it in *C:/Users/username/MountTest*. I created a new container and mounted this directory (MountTest) as a data volume. The command I ran to do so is shown below:

```
docker run -t -i --name mounttest -v /c/Users/sarin/MountTest:/home ubuntu /bin/bash
```

Next, I run the command to execute the script within the container *mounttest*.

```
docker exec -it mounttest sh /home/helloworld.sh
```

The result is as follows:

```
: not foundworld.sh: 2: /home/helloworld.sh:
Hello World
```

I get the desired output (echo Hello World) but I want to understand the reason behind *the not found errors*.

**Note:** This question might look similar to [Run shell script on docker from shared volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34188041/run-shell-script-on-docker-from-shared-volume), but it addresses permission related issues.

**References:**
The *helloworld.sh* file:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo 'Hello World'
```

The mounted volumes information is captured below.
[image]

Comment: Please post exact contents of `helloworld.sh` and your invocation.

Comment: Does `helloworld.sh` by any chance have windows-style line endings (`\r\n`)?

Comment: @Roman No it doesn't.

Comment: @Sarin are you sure? Can you show the output from `docker exec -it mounttest xxd /home/helloworld.sh` ?

Answer (score 1):

Considering the default ENTRYPOINT for the 'ubuntu' image is `sh -c`, the final command executed on `docker exec` is:

```
sh -c 'sh /home/helloworld.sh'
```

It looks a bit strange and might be the cause of the error message.

Try simply:

```
docker exec -it mounttest /home/helloworld.sh
# or
docker exec -it mounttest sh -c '/home/helloworld.sh'
```

Of course, the `docker exec` should be done in a boot2docker ssh session, simalar to the shell session in which you did a `docker run`.
Since the `docker run` opens a bash, you should make a new boot2docker session (docker-machine ssh), and in that new boot2docker shell session, try the `docker exec`.

Trying `docker exec` from within the bash made by `docker run` means trying to do DiD (Docker in Docker). It is not relevant for your test.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, the commands suggested above do not solve the problem. I get the following error, running those commands: 'sh: 1: /home/helloworld.sh: not found'

Comment: @Sarin Just to be sure, are you running `docker exec` just after the `docker run -t -i --name mounttest -v /c/Users/sarin/MountTest:/home ubuntu /bin/bash`? Meaning: are you running `docker exec` within the bash session made by the `docker run`? Because if so, that is not how it works.

Comment: @Sarin I have edited the answer to make clear what command should be typed where.

Comment: I execute the command from outside the bash session. Here is how I do it. 1. Create a container using docker run. 2. Exit the bash session, which also stops the container. 3. Start the container using docker start. 4. Then run docker exec. I am getting errors running other shell scripts as well. In those scripts I create directories which fails as well. Can you shed some light on how you would execute a shell script and maybe share the script.

Comment: @Sarin instead of exiting and restarting the container, try and open a second `docker-machine ssh` session, and test your `docker exec` there.