# Get docker run command for container

Tags: docker

I have a container that I created, but I can't remember the exact `docker run` command I used to kick it off.  Is there any way that can be retrieved?

This is not the same as [See full command of running/stopped container in Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27380641/see-full-command-of-running-stopped-container-in-docker)  What I want to know is the full docker command that spawned the container, not the command within the container.

Comment: It's always `docker run <image name>`, isn't it?

Comment: I think that it's unlikely - docker client uses REST api and docker client commands do not always match the API calls - so it's impossible for server to guess the original command and to store it.

Comment: @ThomasUhrig what about things like port mappings, links, etc.

Comment: @AdamParkin Yeah, you're right!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [See full command of running/stopped container in Docker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27380641/see-full-command-of-running-stopped-container-in-docker)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can infer most of that information by looking at the output of `docker inspect`.

For example, you can discover the command started inside the container by looking at the `Config.Cmd` key.  If I run:

```
$ docker run -v /tmp/data:/data --name sleep -it --rm alpine sleep 600
```

I can later run:

```
$ docker inspect --format '{{.Config.Cmd}}' sleep
```

And get:

```
{[sleep 600]}
```

Similarly, the output of `docker inspect` will also include information about Docker volumes used in the container:

```
$ docker inspect --format '{{.Volumes}}' sleep
map[/data:/tmp/data]
```

You can of course just run `docker inspect` without `--format`, which will give you a big (100+ lines) chunk of JSON output containing all the available keys, which includes information about port mappings, network configuration, and more.