# How can I run a Docker container on a remote server in the same manner as docker-compose up?

Tags: python, docker, nginx, docker-compose

**TL;DR:** Getting error `/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 10: exec: nginx: cannot execute: Is a directory` running `docker run username/srdc_prod:2020.07.26` when `docker-compose up` works just fine.

I have a docker container that I have pushed to DockerHub. I am able to run this locally with docker-compose up. I pulled this down on my remote server and now I am trying to use `docker run username/srdc_prod:2020.07.26`.

When I do this I get the error `/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 10: exec: nginx: cannot execute: Is a directory`. Executing `docker-compose up` works just fine locally. I want to push this image to Docker Hub and pull this down and run it on my remote server. However, I cannot use `docker-compose up` because the `docker-compose.yaml` file does not exist remotely. I realize I could try cloning my GitHub repo remotely and then run `docker-compose up` but this defeats the purpose of pushing the container to DockerHub and eventually getting CI/CD set up.

Is there a way to run docker-compose up on a container? Or is it possible to see all of the commands executed? I saw in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27380641/see-full-command-of-running-stopped-container-in-docker) that I can use `docker ps --no-trunc` to see all of the commands executed for running docker containers, but all of these rely on the `docker-entrypoint.sh` file with which I cannot seem to execute remotely. Am I doing this all wrong and I need to refactor my Dockerfile to run on the remote server?

#### Image on Remote Server

```
username@ubuntu-512mb-name:~$ docker image ls
WARNING: Error loading config file: /home/username/.docker/config.json: stat /home/username/.docker/config.json: permission denied
REPOSITORY                TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
username/srdc_prod        2020.07.26          af62927882ee        5 days ago          504MB
```

#### docker-entrypoint.sh

```
  1 #!/bin/bash
  2
  3 echo "Collect static files"
  4 python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
  5
  6 echo "Apply database migrations"
  7 python manage.py migrate --noinput
  8
  9 echo "Starting daphne server"
 10 exec "$@" # offending line
```

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3-alpine

# set env vars
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN mkdir /app

RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache postgresql-dev gcc libffi-dev musl-dev build-base python3-dev bash

COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install --no-cache-dir -r /app/requirements.txt

COPY test-requirements.txt /app/test-requirements.txt
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install --no-cache-dir -r /app/test-requirements.txt

COPY . /app
# set working directory
WORKDIR /app

RUN mkdir -p /var/www/srdc/static/
RUN chmod 755 /var/www/srdc/static/

EXPOSE 8000

ENV DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=srdc.settings

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

ADD docker-entrypoint.sh /docker-entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod a+x /docker-entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

#### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  django_web:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8000 srdc.asgi:application"
    expose:
       - 8000
    image: srdc:v0
    container_name: srdc_django_web
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - static_volume:/var/www/srdc/static/
    depends_on:
      - db
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/var/www/srdc/static/
      - ./data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
    depends_on:
      - django_web
  db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: "my_postgres"
    ports:
      - "54320:5432"
    volumes:                                                                                                                                                                                     - my_dbdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes:                                                                                                                                                                                       my_dbdata:
    static_volume:                                                                                                                                                                             media_volume:
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but in your Dockerfile you don't appear to be installing nginx, yet your `CMD` is `nginx  -g ...`.  Should that command be `daphne ...`?

Comment: There is a directory called 'nginx' that has a Dockerfile. I should probably include that.

Comment: But that's the `Dockerfile` for the `nginx` service, right?  Your question appears to be about the `django_web` service, based on the image you're running (`srdc_prod`), which doesn't need `nginx`'s `Dockerfile`.  You have three containers listed, and it looks like you're running the `nginx` command in the wrong one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're seeing is accurate: `nginx` is a directory.  Based on your `docker-compose.yml` manifset, there is an `nginx` folder in your root directory which you use as a build context for your `nginx` service.

```
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx # Here's the evidence for the nginx folder.
    ports:
```

When you build the `django_web` image, you copy over the entire context directory into `/app`, and that includes the `nginx` directory.

```
COPY . /app
# set working directory
WORKDIR /app
```

The `CMD` for your `username/srdc_prod` image is `nginx -g daemon off;`, which your `docker-entrypoint.sh` executes.  That fails because `nginx` is a directory.

Based on your `docker-compose.yml` manifest, it looks like the `CMD` you actually want is `daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8000 srdc.asgi:application` or something like that, but not `nginx` which is not installed in that alpine-based image.

Some recommendations outside of the scope of the question.

1. If you're using docker-compose in dev, consider using that in your hosted environments, too, instead of running the raw `docker run` commands.
2. Better yet, use Docker in swarm mode.  You can re-use your manifest file that way, albeit you would need to remove some of the deprecated stuff (`depends_on`, for example) and expand on the service definitions a bit.  Using swarm mode--or some other orchestration tool--will make it easier to scale your service in the future, plus you get some other handy features like secrets, restart policies, network segregation, and so on.

Comment: Thank you. Can you elaborate on this `If you're using docker-compose in dev, consider using that in your hosted environments, too, instead of running the raw docker run commands.`? I did not see an easy way to do this without cloning the repo onto the remote server. I'll look into swarm mode. Thanks!

Comment: Generally you don't need to put anything on the remote server except for a docker-compose.yml file, and maybe some env files for configuration.  All of the images should exist in the cloud in some container registry, and each image should have everything it needs to run (i.e. all the application code and assets and whatnot).  In the YAML file you shared, the django container mounts the `./app` directory, but in the built image `app` is copied into the container.  As such, you should not need to clone the repo on the remote server.

Comment: So in this setup I need to maintain two separate docker-compose.yaml files? Do you have any links you can point me to run docker-compose in prod? Thanks!

Comment: I don't have any links, sorry.  I use Docker Swarm in prod, QA, and UAT. I personally only use a single docker-compose.yml file across all environments, but I have separate environment files for each env.  IMO, the service definitions should be identical across all environments, and things that change from env to env should be configurable using environment variables.